# Could not convert '&L' from 'List*' to 'List'

Tags: c, string, pointers, parameters, compiler-errors

I make a code with non-Binary Tree, but, my code still error in drive. The error said "could not convert '&L' from 'List*' to 'List'"
This is the header

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char infotype[15];
typedef struct tElmtList *address;
typedef struct tElmtList {
    infotype info;
    address pw;
    address fs;
    address nb;
    address pf;
}ElmtList;

typedef struct {
    address First;
} List;
```

This is the cpp.

```
void CreateList (List *L){
    First(*L) = NULL;
}

address Alokasi (infotype X){
    address P;
    P = (address) malloc (sizeof (ElmtList));
    if (P != NULL){
        strcpy (P->info, X);
        P->pw = NULL;
        P->fs = NULL;
        P->nb = NULL;
        P->pf = NULL;
    }
    return (P);
}

void BuatNode (List *L, address y){
    infotype X;
    printf ("Masukkan string = ");
    scanf ("%s", &X);
    y = Alokasi(X);
    if (L->First == NULL){
        L->First = y;
    }
}

void TambahRaja (List *L){
    address y;
    if (L->First == NULL){
        BuatNode(*L, y);
        L->First = y;
    } else {
        printf("Raja sudah ada. Tidak bisa menambah raja.");
    }
}
```

And this is the drive.

```
int main (){
    List L;
    CreateList(&L);
    int pil;
    for(;;){
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\tMain Menu\n");
        printf("1. Menambahkan Raja.\n");
        printf("2. Menambahkan Pendamping.\n");
        printf("3. Menambahkan Anak.\n");
        printf("4. Menampilkan List.\n");
        printf("5. Keluar.\n");
        printf("Masukkan pilihan :");
        scanf("%d", &pil);
        switch(pil){
            case 1 : {
                TambahRaja(&L);
                break;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Please help me, i think i'ts error in parameters i used. I still confuse in pointer with '*'. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where's `CreateList`, please?

Comment: This is the CreateList `void CreateList (List *L){
 First(*L) = NULL;
}`

Comment: Which line does the error refer to? There should be a line number in the error message. `BuatNode(*L, y);` is wrong, it would just be `BuatNode(L, y);`. You're better off not using `typedef` to hide pointers, such as `typedef struct tElmtList *address;`.

Comment: Oh, i see. @RetiredNinja the line error in main, which i called the `void TambahRaja(&L)` in drive

Comment: @Bee__Nanaa thanks -- could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68310687/edit) that into your post please? Ideally, there is a copy-pasteable [mcve] that can be executed.

Comment: Sorry, but if I take only the relevant bits of code -- that function, the struct, and the call, that works fine for me.

Comment: Unfortunately the line you've said the error is on isn't an error in the code you've shown. There are other issues, `BuatNode(*L, y);` and the `CreateList` function you provided in a comment are both errors. `scanf ("%s", &X);` also generates a warning, the `&` is incorrect. I'd advise correcting those issues and if you're still having trouble creating a single code block [mcve] that demonstrates and clearly marks any issues.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I will try first @RetiredNinja

Comment: The posted code doesn't generate the problem described. The posted code must differ from your local version. Anyway... `First(*L) = NULL;` is wrong. Probably you want `L->First = NULL;`

Comment: What is `First()`? What do you mean with "this is cpp" and "this is drive"? Are those different C files? You mention only C but `cpp` sounds as if you are using C++?

Comment: Not causing any error, but you should not hide pointers in typedefs and casting return value of `malloc` is also frowned upon.